# Custom graph with Core Graphics and choppy frame rate when calling touchesMoved

Tags: iphone, performance, core-graphics, graphing, touchesmoved

I am creating a custom graph inside a UIView within the drawRect method using core graphics. The problem I am having is moving that graph with the user dragging their finger. For example, if my graph has 500 points and the screen is only 320 pixels wide, I can only show a subset of those points and the rest can be accessed when touching and dragging to see the rest of the graph[image: See this image]

The problem i am facing is touched moved makes dragging the graph fairly choppy and isn't as quick and responsive as I'd like. I am open to other suggestions besides using CoreGraphics, but it seemed like the best choice. Please see my drawRect method below and thanks in advance!

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
//[self initGraph];

// grab the current view graphics context
// the context is basically our invisible canvas that we draw into.
CGContextRef context    = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextClearRect( context , [self bounds] );

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
int spread = 1;
spread = (int)ceil((double)self.bounds.size.width/(double)[graphPoints count]);
int xTrace = 0;
int firstX = 0;
int firstY = 0; 
int count=0;
for(NSDecimalNumber *aPoint in graphPoints){
    int yPos = [self priceToPoint:aPoint];
    if(yPos < 0){
        yPos = 1;
    }
    if(count==0){
        firstX = xTrace;
        firstY = yPos;
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, (xTrace+xOffset)+lastOffset, yPos);
    }else{
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, (xTrace+xOffset)+lastOffset, yPos);
    }
    xTrace = xTrace+spread;
    count++;
}
xTrace = xTrace-spread;
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, (xTrace+xOffset)+lastOffset, self.bounds.size.height);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, firstX,firstY);
// setup the gradient
CGFloat locations[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
CGFloat components[8] = {
    0.0/255.0, 94.0/255.0, 143.0/255.0, 1.0,  // Start color
    61.0/255.0, 110.0/255.0, 135.0/255.0, 1.0   // End color
};
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGGradientRef gradientFill = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (colorSpace, components, locations, 2);

// setup gradient points
CGRect pathRect = CGPathGetBoundingBox(path);
CGPoint myStartPoint, myEndPoint;
myStartPoint.x = CGRectGetMinX(pathRect);
myStartPoint.y = CGRectGetMinY(pathRect);
myEndPoint.x = CGRectGetMaxX(pathRect);
myEndPoint.y = CGRectGetMinY(pathRect);

// draw the gradient
CGContextAddPath(context, path);
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextClip(context);
CGContextDrawLinearGradient (context, gradientFill, myStartPoint, myEndPoint, 0);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);

// draw the dash
CGContextAddPath(context, path);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context,87.0/255.0,155.0/255.0,191.0/255.0,0.8);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

// cleanup
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGGradientRelease(gradientFill);
CGPathRelease(path);
```

}

Comment: Is the data being rendered in real time? If not, you could render the whole thing in advance, and put the whole rendered (oversized) graph in a horizontal scroll view.

Comment: the data is being rendered in real-time, so can't be pre rendered unfortunately...although, it does give me an idea...perhaps I can render the path as needed and do a transformation when the user scrolls the graph....thanks :) will report back with a solution